# Merging several Arraylists <String> into one

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

Ok so I want to merge these arrayslist in such a way that they slot into one another and create the sentence below. 
Output: “This is the sentence that I’m trying to reconstruct”

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(This, , , , , , , , reconstruct);
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList (, is, the, , , , trying, ,);
List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList(, , ,sentence, that, I'm, , to,);
```

I’ve tried to use the  list.addall(list2) but it just places each list right next to the other. How can I integrate the list?

Comment: You can create an array with the `length = size` from list and add the content to the array at the specific place if  `content!=""`

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like below

```
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("This", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", " reconstruct");
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("", " is", " the", "", "", "", " trying", "", "");
    List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("", "", "", " sentence", " that", " I'm", "", " to", "");

    StringBuilder sentense = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        sentense.append(list1.get(i)).append(list2.get(i)).append(list3.get(i));
    }
    System.out.print(sentense.toString());
```

Comment: Adding space before each word (except first one) doesn't look right. You can avoid it by using StringJoiner with space as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that given lists have same size. You can use code similar to this.

```
  for(int i =0; i<list1.size();i++){
    if(list1.get(i)==""){

    //replace with sentence from other lists 
        if(list2.get(i)!=""){
           list1.add(i,list2.get(i));
        }
        else if(list3.get(i)!=""){
           list1.add(i,list3.get(i));
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will only work if you are sure that every position of the words is unique:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(This, , , , , , , , reconstruct);
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList (, is, the, , , , trying, ,);
List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList(, , ,sentence, that, I'm, , to,);

String txt = "";
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    txt = txt + list1.get(i) + list2.get(i) + list3.get(i) + " ";
}
System.out.println(txt.trim());
```

If you want to create a new list do this:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
String txt = "";
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    txt = list1.get(i) + list2.get(i) + list3.get(i);
    myList.add(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I hope that this can help

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("This", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "reconstruct");
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList ("", "is", "the", "", "", "", "trying", "","");
    List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("", "", "","sentence", "that", "Im", "", "to","");
    List<String> mergedValue = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i<list1.size();i++){
        if(list1.get(i)!=""){
            mergedValue.add(list1.get(i));
        }
        if(list2.get(i)!=""){
            mergedValue.add(list2.get(i));
        }
        if(list3.get(i)!=""){
            mergedValue.add(list3.get(i));
        }
    }
```